# Weird output using the scrollView and Constraint layout

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:theme="?attr/actionBarTheme"
        android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp" />


    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView"
        android:layout_width="368dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/toolbar2"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent">

        <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            android:id="@+id/constraint_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView5"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:paddingBottom="4dp"
                android:paddingTop="4dp"
                android:text="Customer Name"
                android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/customer_name"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent" />


            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/customer_name"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="Name"
                android:inputType="textPersonName"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/textView5"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
  </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

 </ScrollView>
```

Please check the output of this image [image: here].

Both side content is going out of the screen. I don't why? I am even specifying the margin left and right 16dp(8dp+8dp). But I don't think it is working out. 
Why is it behaving weirdly? Is it because I am testing on android version 4.2.1?
Or there is any reason?

OS- 4.2.1

I have checked it on 5.1.1 it is working fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output is like that because:

1. No `android:orientation` was specified in the `ConstraintLayout`(which defaults to `"horizontal"`)
2. The `android:layout_width` value is set to `"wrap_content"`

Three solutions for you :

1. Change `android:orientation` in your `ConstraintLayout` to `"vertical"` and set `android:layout_width` of your `TextView` and `EditText` to `match_parent`
2. Set `android:layout_width` of your two Views to `0dp`, and then use `android:weight`.
3. **(The best solution)** Delete the `TextView`, set `android:layout_width` of the `EditText` to `match_parent`. Then use `android:hint` on the `EditText` like this :

   ```
   android:hint = "Customer Name"
   ```

Comment: If this is the problem then how it is working on the lollipop?

Comment: Is it because the sizes of the screens are different ?